# openvpn server does not route traffic from clients to private network

Tags: routing, openvpn, nat

**UPDATE**:

it should have been `10.100.0.0/24` instead of `10.100.0.0/32`. now it works

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**:

i have multiple hosts running in private network **10.99.0.0/24**. one of them is my openvpn-server and is reachable over internet. i want my openvpn-clients to be able to reach the other hosts in 10.99.0.0/24 once they are connected to openvpn-server.

right now i can connect to vpn, but i can not reach hosts from 10.99.0.0/24 and i do not know why.

here is the content of my `server.conf` on openvpn-server:

```
port 22094
dev tun
topology subnet
server 10.100.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
proto udp
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-GCM
comp-lzo
verb 3

push "route 10.99.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

on openvpn-clients this route is added once they connect to vpn:

```
10.99.0.0   255.255.0.0   10.100.0.1   10.100.0.4   257
```

on openvpn-server `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns **1**

iptables are all empty. i have tried adding `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.0.0/32 -j MASQUERADE`, but it did not help.

when i run `tcpdump` on my openvpn-server i can see traffic from my client to hosts in 10.99.0.0/24 (f.e. when i try to ping or ssh), but it looks like the traffic does not reach the hosts.

what am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the opposite problem, i.e. that traffic _from the hosts_ can't reach the VPN server because they don't have the right routes?

Comment: running `tcpdump` on hosts in in 10.99.0.0/24 shows no traffic, thus my assumption

Comment: Does tcpdump on the VPN server show packets going out to the correct interface, and to the correct MAC address (with `-e`)?

Comment: i run `tcpdump` with `-i` and check traffic from expected (outgoing-)interface and i can see f.e. `10.100.0.4.51447 > 10.99.0.4.ssh`, but nothing is comming back.

Comment: `10.100.0.0/32` should have been `10.100.0.0/24`... now it works